# How to split secret variables into different template files on gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a template file on gitlab:

```
.secrets:
  GROUP_A_secret_a:
  vault: GroupA/seca@default
  GROUP_B_secret_a:
  vault: GroupB/seca@default
  GROUP_A_secret_b:
  vault: GroupA/secb@default
  GROUP_B_secret_b:
  vault: GroupA/secb@default
```

And then I refer to those secrets on gitlab jos as:

```
secrets: !reference [ .secrets ]
```

How do I split them into .secretsA and .secretsB and refer them in the gitlab job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [sytech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747944/sytech), answered, I would say a slight modification to make it work and little better.

Have the secrets in different files:

file "/.secretsA.yml"

```
.secretsA
  secrets:
    GROUP_A_secret_a:
      vault: GroupA/seca@default
    # ... and so on
```

file "/.secretsB.yml"

```
.secretsB
  secrets:
    GROUP_B_secret_b:
      vault: GroupA/secb@default
    # ... and so on
```

file /.secrets_default.yml

```
include:
 - local: /.secretsA.yml
 - local: /.secretsB.yml

.secrets_default:
  extends:
    - .secretsA
    - .secretsB
```

You can now have your job have all the secrets by extending .secrets_default:

file ".gitlab-ci.yml"

```
include:
  - /.secrets_default.yml

my-job:
  extends: .secrets_default
```

In this way you can cleanly, have all secrets for your job on gitlab

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a hash map consisting of two different `!reference` sources. You can merge hashes using `extends:` though. However, because your hidden key isn't in a format that allows `extends:` to be used directly, you need a couple extra steps...

Assuming you have used `include:` to include the files containing `.secretsA` and `.secretsB`, you could use `extends:` to merge the configurations.

```yaml
# These are needed to put these in the correct job format...
# This could be skipped if `.secretsA` used valid formats instead
.my_secretsA:
  secrets: !reference [.secretsA]
.my_secretsB:
  secrets: !reference [.secretsB]

# Then they can be combined using `extends:`
myjob:
  extends:
    - .my_secretsA
    - .my_secretsB
```

---

Alternatively... if you formatted your secrets like so:

```
.secretsA
  secrets:
    GROUP_A_secret_a:
      vault: GroupA/seca@default
    # ... and so on

.secretsB
  secrets:
    GROUP_B_secret_b:
      vault: GroupA/secb@default
    # ... and so on
```

Then they could just be used with `extends:` directly:

```yaml
myjob:
  extends:
    - .secretsA
    - .secretsB
```

And could still be used individually (when only one set is needed) with `!reference` if you choose not to use extends:

```yaml
myjob:
  secrets: !reference [.secretsA, secrets]
```